# Anyone knows how to extract the attachment within a PDF file using python?

Tags: python, pdf

I have 2,000+ pdf with attachments and I want to bulk extract them. Does anyone who has any clue?

Comment: For loop over os.listdir.

Comment: Yeah I can access the pdf, but how to extract the attachments within those pdfs?

Comment: [python extract pdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+extract+pdf)